# Insert and select the id of a unique element in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table like this

```
CREATE TABLE authid(
  id      INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  authid  VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Now if I insert a value with

```
INSERT INTO authid(authid) VALUES('test');
```

It will work fine and return the inserted id the first time, but if I do it again when the authid already exists (notice that we have authid marked as UNIQUE) it will return an error.

Is there a way achieve this this in one SQL statement: Insert it, get the id and if it already exists, still get the id.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Are you asking how to get the auto-incremented ID of a newly inserted record?  Or are you asking about something with the unique constraint?

Comment: I want to insert a entry into the table, if the entry already exists, get its id, if it doesn't, create it and get it's id.

Comment: This issue has been pounded on here... IF EXISTS in a stored procedure is the best way to go (as I remember.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

If you're using MySQL 5.0 or higher you can use the "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" syntax.  You may be able to combine that with LAST_INSERT_ID() (I'm not positive about that)

So:

```
insert into authid (authid) values ('test') on duplicate key update id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), authid='test';
select LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: so if test exists it puts test there, and then does a select anyway. heck why not delete the row and do an insert !

Comment: let's say there was such a function/command. it would just be tricking you into thinking it wasn't doing a select and insert anyway, and the runtime-performance would be the same. so move on to the bigger fish you have to fry Andrius

Comment: The first SQL statement should return the ID in both cases, i'll check it out.

Comment: Andrius, check out the very last example of that link I posted... I'll update my post

Comment: the sad thing is that let's say the select stmt takes 10 units of time and the insert takes 40. instead of accepting your 10, you force mysql to do it in something greater than 40 because it has to mess with the UNIQUE index as it assumes the unique value has changed. without benchmarking it you have no idea that you are taking a performance hit

Comment: I updated my example.  By adding id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id) to the update portion of the query, it seeds the LAST_INSERT_ID value so it becomes meaningful from the UPDATE.

Comment: now run it a million times compared to the original select/insert and let us know the time differences

Comment: Drew, if anything I would assume this is more efficient - or at least AS efficient.  It's probably doing nothing more than a `if exists (select by unique id) update else insert` from a low level.

Comment: no, it is not doing an exist select. it is forcing and update/insert with data on top of what is already there. remember, you were the one that said originally (until u changed the question) that "Because an insert and a select in two sql statements take two times longer."   ... which is not a true stmt. a select is fast

Answer (score 0):

Well indeed if you try to insert 2 times the same value in a UNIQUE field, it won't work, that's the point of UNIQUE fields.

If I understand well, you want to know if it's possible whether to use an INSERT or an UPDATE statement depending on the existance of an item or not ? Then you need 2 queries, 1 to test existence, the other to insert new value or update existing one

Answer (score 0):

Insert the value conditionally (i.e. if it doesn't exist). Whether the insert takes place or not, by the end of the statement the result will be the same: the value will be in the table. So, just select the ID of the row that matches that value. Or, speaking in SQL, like this:

```
INSERT INTO authid (authid)
SELECT 'test'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM authid
    WHERE authid = 'test'
);

SELECT id
FROM authid
WHERE authid = 'test'
;
```